# use css() method with background-image css property

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to use css() method of jquery. But problem is when i am using css() method for display none it works fine but when i replace it to background-image property then css() not working at all. Whats wrong i am doing here? Please note: the background-image picture will load from hosted link like code bellow.

Working code:

```
$("#register-page").css({"display" : "none"  });
```

Not works:

```
$("#register-page").css({"background-image" : "url("https://academy.zikanalytics.com/wp-content/themes/boss-child/buddypress/members/gears.svg")"  });
```

Comment: `$("#register-page").css({"background-image" : "url('https://academy.zikanalytics.com/wp-content/themes/boss-child/buddypress/members/gears.svg')"  });` <- try

Comment: You need to use alternating quote types, ie. `'` for the outer string then `"` within the string. Voting to close as a typographical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the background image via pure CSS or JQuery as you are, the display element is sticking to its previous value as it's never really changed.

```
$("#register-page").css({
  "background-image": "url('https://academy.zikanalytics.com/wp-content/themes/boss-child/buddypress/members/gears.svg')", 
  "display": "block"
});
```

Comment: nah this also not works. can u provide a working fiddle?

Comment: There is an extra `"` on `...ers/gears.svg"')",`

Comment: Indeed, updated the answer. In-fact, the guy who editted my response accidently put it in there as I just watched the modifications he made.

Comment: @Luicy apologies. I edited as you were and attempted to add the changes you had made. In future, please ensure you format your code samples properly so they are readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the wrong use of `"` and `'`

```
$("#register-page").css({"background-image" : "url('https://academy.zikanalytics.com/wp-content/themes/boss-child/buddypress/members/gears.svg')"  });
```